# How to integrate Accelerated Mobile Pages in Magento project

Tags: php, magento, seo, amp-html

I have started integrating the AMP concept in my current Magento live project.

I have did below things.

one test html file in www folder as suggested here, https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup.html this worked great.

I have did in my magento project, in 1column.phtml,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
```

in head.phtml, added first line as below

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

I am running home page by appending `#development=1`. and getting the error in console as below:

```
TypeError: aa.Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(...) is not a non-null object
(var e in b)aa.Object.defineProperties?aa.Object.defineProperty(a,e,aa.Object.ge...
  validator.js (line 2, col 221)

ReferenceError: amp is not defined
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The approach does not look right , you need to add rel="amphtml" attribute for all of your product and category pages with source url of your amp pages . You may check the structure of the page here http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-amp-template/ we have implemented AMP in magento2 .

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>"
```

first 2 lines should be like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
```

Comment: I have tried this. But unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Answer (score -2):

What might be more simple is using an extension to integrate AMP into your Magento store. I've used the one described created by coding basics: http://codingbasics.net/accelerated-mobile-pages-magento/

Really simple to set it up, and it works flawlessly. Don't know if you've already fixed this issue as some time has passed but I thought I'd reply anyway to help you and others out.